# Почему mask с градиентом внутри, примененная к изображению, не работает?

Tags: svg

```html
<svg width='400' height='400' style='border: 1px solid black'>
  
<radialGradient id='a'>
  <stop offset='40%' stop-color='red'></stop>
  <stop offset='60%' stop-color='blue'></stop>
</radialGradient>

<mask id='b'>
  <circle r="50" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="url(#a)" />
</mask>
<image x="50%" y="50%" width="291" height="195"
       mask="url(#b)" xlink:href="https://i.ibb.co/1XcpWKV/0E5BJ.png"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: в маску надо положить rect со 100% шириной и высотой в fill="#fff"

Comment: а если я хочу круг чтобы был ?

Comment: проверь а потом если не получится - напиши

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как указал в комментариях @MaximLensky, чтобы маска заработала, необходимо добавить в маску

```
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" />
```

Это делает всю область изображения видимым, то есть не обрезается маской.

При применении в маске заполнения цветами отличающимися от белого, маска делает участок изображения  полупрозрачным.
`При fill="black"`, участок изображения, к которому применена маска, вырезается. Подробнее [тут](http://svg-art.ru/?p=1862)

Используемое изображение имеет размеры `400 х 143px` поэтому немного изменил исходный код

```html
<svg width='400' height='400' style='border: 1px solid black'>
  
<radialGradient id='a'>
  <stop offset='40%' stop-color='red'></stop>
  <stop offset='60%' stop-color='blue'></stop>
</radialGradient>

<mask id='b'> 
   <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" />
  <circle r="50" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="url(#a)" />
</mask>
<image x="50%" y="50%" width="400" height="143"
       mask="url(#b)" xlink:href="https://i.ibb.co/1XcpWKV/0E5BJ.png"/>

</svg>
```

*При <image x="0%" y="50%"*

```html
<svg width='400' height='400' style='border: 1px solid black'>
  
<radialGradient id='a'>
  <stop offset='40%' stop-color='red'></stop>
  <stop offset='60%' stop-color='blue'></stop>
</radialGradient>

<mask id='b'> 
   <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" />
  <circle r="50" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="url(#a)" />
</mask>
<image x="0%" y="50%" width="400" height="143"
       mask="url(#b)" xlink:href="https://i.ibb.co/1XcpWKV/0E5BJ.png"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @Leks всегда рад помочь

Answer (score 1):

Если я Вас правильно понял то должно быть что-то вроде этого.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
        <svg width='1241' height='823' style='border: 1px solid black'>
            <radialGradient id='a'>
                <stop offset='40%' stop-color='red'></stop>
                <stop offset='60%' stop-color='blue'></stop>
            </radialGradient>
            <symbol id="s-mask">
                <circle r="350" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="url(#a)" />
            </symbol>
            <mask id='b' x="0" y="0">
                <use xlink:href="#s-mask"></use>
            </mask>
            <image mask="url(#b)" xlink:href="https://www.dlt.travel/immagine/46566/Tour_virtural_Taj_mahal.jpg"/>        
        </svg>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Обратите внимание на тэг **USE**.